# $parts became null what should i do now? what i have to change and how?

Tags: php

```
$baseUrl = config('base_url');
$fullUrl = "{$_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']}://{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";

$uri = str_replace($baseUrl,'',$fullUrl);
$parts = explode('/',$uri);
```

Comment: This means `$baseUrl` is the same as `$fullUrl`.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the values at each stage to see what they contain?

Comment: When you edit your questions to add some things, please retain some of the updates other users have made (i.e. formatting code).

Comment: What is `$baseUrl` and what is `$fullUrl`?